# how can i call HTTP callable cloud function from postman?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I want to know that can i call cloud function from postman software .When i'm calling CF from postman it always give me

```
 "error": {
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide the sample URL for your request

Comment: have you tried with curl ? curl -X POST "https://YOUR_REGION-YOUR_PROJECT_ID.cloudfunctions.net/FUNCTION_NAME" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"name":"Keyboard Cat"}' . ... If it works then let me know..  then we will try with postman also.

Comment: update your request url in the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 13):

In Postman make post request, header `Content-Type` should be `application/json` and then in raw make json in this format

```
{
    "data": {
    "text":"hi how are you",
    "phoneNumbers":"+92123455679"
    }
}
```

Comment: I am receiving a 401 error message as an authenticated user. Do you know any work around for that?

Answer (score 13):

Using @Vaaljan's answer I was able to authenticate a GCP cloud function that I created using the HTTP trigger method with authentication required:

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```

Then added it to the request Authorization header:

```
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6I ... bnRzLmdvb2dsZS5jb20i
```

In Postman:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Could possibly also be that the cloud function is protected and can be invoked by adding Authorization header with the identity token as the Bearer.

You get the identity token by running

```
gcloud auth print-identity-token
```