# Securing HTTP endpoints of Cloud Functions - GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created CF on GCP console, some are trigggered by Firestore and some are HTTP Endpoints. I have secured former one using Firebase Auth, but the later one HTTP Endpoints are not secured as i didnt find any way to authenticate them. Please help as i am new to GCP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Secure Google Cloud Functions http trigger with auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358013/secure-google-cloud-functions-http-trigger-with-auth)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/authorized-https-endpoint)'s a code sample that shows how to only allow users that use a Firebase ID token as a Bearer in the `Authorization` header of the HTTP request or in a `__session` cookie to trigger the Cloud Function.

Alternatively [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46358013/secure-google-cloud-functions-http-trigger-with-auth) StackOverflow post may be of help.

Comment: How can i call http authenicate cloud function(Untick unauthenticated option) using postman ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Postman, thus the help I can provide is limited. Anyhow, here's a post that explains how to trigger a Cloud Function with Postman: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264001/how-can-i-call-http-callable-cloud-function-from-postman. Putting this and my previous answer's suggestions together you may come up with something that you're looking for.