# Weird behaviour/issues on Google Cloud Function (https trigger)

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am new to Goggle Cloud Function and so I am not sure what my bug can be as it varies from tests to tests

First, let's have some code:

```
package my_test

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "{source_host}/{project}/my_test/models"
    "net/http"
)

// HttpMain prints the JSON encoded "UserId" field in the body
// of the request.
func HttpMain(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var body models.Body

    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&body); err != nil {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w,"%v\n", err)
    }

    err := Run(w, &body)
    if err != nil {
        _, _ = fmt.Fprintf(w,"%v\n", err)
    }

    _, _ = fmt.Fprintln(w, "Done")
}

// Run the core part of the function itself.
func Run(w http.ResponseWriter, body *models.Body) error {

    if body == nil {
        return errors.New("body parameter is nil")
    } else if body.UserId == "" {
        return errors.New("body.UserId is empty")
    } else {
        _, err := fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n", body.UserId)
        return err
    }

}
```

and the body model comes like this:

```
package models

type Body struct {
    UserId string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=UserId,proto3" json:"UserId,omitempty"`
}
```

---

## The Deployment (OK)

I've made a simple shell script which deploys my function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

name="my_test"
entryPoint="HttpMain"

yes Y | gcloud functions deploy ${name} --trigger-http --entry-point ${entryPoint} --region europe-west1 --runtime go113 --allow-unauthenticated
```

The function gets deployed, everything is ok.

---

## The weird behavior/issue...

Well right now... I have 3 tests and each of them throws a different error, and I totally don't get why:

---

> Gcloud command-line

Let's start with the command-line tool itself. I have this test:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

name="my_test"

gcloud functions call ${name} --region europe-west1 --data "{\"UserId\":\"Hey yo buddy\"}"
```

*Result:*

```
macbook-pro-de-emixam23:my_test emixam23$ ./test.sh 
error: 'Error: cannot communicate with function.'
```

*Logs:*

```
D 2020-04-30T09:36:13.702363769Z my_test s1tyqfgxld9u Function execution started my_test s1tyqfgxld9u 
A 2020-04-30T09:36:13.723Z my_test s1tyqfgxld9u 2020/04/30 09:36:13 project id is required to access Firestore my_test s1tyqfgxld9u 
D 2020-04-30T09:36:13.813514210Z my_test s1tyqfgxld9u Function execution took 104 ms, finished with status: 'connection error' my_test s1tyqfgxld9u
```

---

> Postman

I then tried from Postman:

`https://europe-west1-{PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/my_test`

```
{
    "data": {
        "UserId":"Hey yo buddy"
    }
}
```

**Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/58210273/6093604 for a better understanding of data field**

*Result:*

```
body.UserId is empty
Done
```

*Logs:*

```
D 2020-04-30T09:40:35.019776155Z my_test 9orqtgampnqz Function execution started my_test 9orqtgampnqz 
D 2020-04-30T09:40:35.246508146Z my_test 9orqtgampnqz Function execution took 227 ms, finished with status code: 200 my_test 9orqtgampnqz
```

---

> Terminal

I then tried from the terminal using cURL, but again another new issue...

```
macbook-pro-de-emixam23:~ emixam23$ curl -X POST "https://europe-west1-{PROJECT_ID}.cloudfunctions.net/my_test" -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data '{"UserId":"azerty"}'
```

*Result:*

```
Error: could not handle the request
```

*Logs:*

```
D 2020-04-30T09:41:51.645842954Z my_test k856kvp2bhun Function execution started my_test k856kvp2bhun 
A 2020-04-30T09:41:51.698Z my_test k856kvp2bhun 2020/04/30 09:41:51 project id is required to access Firestore my_test k856kvp2bhun 
D 2020-04-30T09:41:51.712630551Z my_test k856kvp2bhun Function execution took 67 ms, finished with status: 'connection error' my_test k856kvp2bhun
```

---

So what the hell is going on... How is that possible that, following the doc, I get 3 differents errors...

- error: 'Error: cannot communicate with function.'
- Empty unmarshalled json
- Error: could not handle the request

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it...

Ok alright, I might have not put an information which was "Hey guys, I use Firestore". As I was thinking first, my files/folders gets uploaded and "voilà". Well, No.

Two things must be taken in consideration:

- Your files/folders starting with a '.' aren't getting uploaded (.credentials folder by exemple.......)
- When your code gets uploaded, it isn't getting upload in the root of the destination deployment, it gets uploaded in "/src/{your_package_name}" (So be careful with the path you give when you want to load files such as your credentials)

How did I solve it and got to know that? Not from a doc, again... I simmulated a "ls -la" which logged me all the files/folders...

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the logs under google console for more details and pass it here 
Thank you.

Comment: As you see here project id is required to access, i think you need to use the flag --project {project_id} when u call the function https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--project

Comment: I did so but same.. By looking at the log tho, I could see that their talking about Firestore, which I use later on in my cloud function. Now, the thing I don't get is why it works in local? You could say *you set up your machin with gcloud, that's why.* -> Ok but regarding my credentials (json file), project id is set inside..

Comment: The end goal would be to plug it to Firestore on "Insert" in a certain collection, but I need to debug it first and I am not even able to do it...

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/rollbacks-and-infinite-loops-with-firestore-and-cloud-functions-in-golang-263aa76398da 
check this it may be useful (Sorry i couldn't be helpful)

Comment: It seems like I have my .credentials/ which is not upload at deploy time and instead of telling that credentials were not found, it provides another error message, I am testing to confirm

Comment: check your IAM role also (cloudfunctions.functions.call)

Comment: Hey any update on the `./credentials` being the cause? @GeeketteTN